# Cannot eject USB drive on XP even after TFileStream is freed

Tags: delphi, usb, drive

I am using Delphi XE3. Below is my code:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: Byte;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    FileStream := TFileStream.Create(SaveDialog1.FileName, fmCreate or fmOpenWrite or fmShareExclusive);
    try
      FileStream.Write(Data, SizeOf(Data));
    finally
      FreeAndNil(FileStream);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When using this code to write data to a file on a USB drive, I find that even though the file stream is freed, I still cannot eject the USB drive under Windows XP. The system says the USB drive is still in use. I need to close the whole program to eject the USB drive.

However, under Windows 7, there is no such a problem.

Why?

Comment: I had this problem from time to time, too. But with external HDDs and USB drives and with “normal“ usage (e.g. Explorer), not especially Delphi streams. So I think, that's a Win XP bug! Conclusion: stop using Win XP! ;-)

Comment: The anti-virus could be busy scanning the drive.

Comment: Anti virus is most likely the culprit. Also, I don't think you need any flags beyond fmCreate.

Comment: Use Russinovich's [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) by searching for the filename - if it is still open check if it's your process or another.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I do not install any anti-virus program on that computer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thank you. I remove all flags except fmCreate, but the issue still exists.

Comment: No, removing those flags won't change the behaviour. So they are pointless.